# Periodic database backup in kubernetes?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, kubernetes

How to setup periodic database backup in kubernetes? I have deployed a postgres database as `StatefulSet` in kubernetes and mounted a `PersistantVolume` to store data. Now to get periodic backup for the mounted volume, I found three options,

1. Setup a `CronJob` in kubernetes and execute pg_dump and upload to the storage location.
2. I have already using celery in my project. So now add a new task to backup postgres data and upload to the storage location.
3. VolumeSnapshots. This looks more kubernetes way. But I couldn't find a way to automate this periodically.

Which is the recommended way to take periodic volume backup in kubernetes?

[EDIT] I prefer solutions without using operators.

Answer (score 2):

> Which is the recommended way to take periodic volume backup in kubernetes?

I would recommend [VolumeSnapshots](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/), but you need to keep in mind that this is not normal backup and you won't be able to revert the data to previous state.

> Many storage systems (like Google Cloud Persistent Disks, Amazon Elastic Block Storage, and many on-premise storage systems) provide the ability to create a “snapshot” of a persistent volume. A snapshot represents a point-in-time copy of a volume. A snapshot can be used either to provision a new volume (pre-populated with the snapshot data) or to restore an existing volume to a previous state (represented by the snapshot).

It's easy to use, as of December 2019 it was moved to beta [Kubernetes 1.17 Feature: Kubernetes Volume Snapshot Moves to Beta](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/12/09/kubernetes-1-17-feature-cis-volume-snapshot-beta/).

Once you specify the `VolumeSnapshotClass`

> The following VolumeSnapshotClass, for example, tells the Kubernetes cluster that a CSI driver,  `testdriver.csi.k8s.io`, can handle volume snapshots, and that when these snapshots are created, their deletion policy should be to delete.
>
> ```yaml
> apiVersion: snapshot.storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
> kind: VolumeSnapshotClass
> metadata:
>  name: test-snapclass
> driver: testdriver.csi.k8s.io
> deletionPolicy: Delete
> parameters:
>  csi.storage.k8s.io/snapshotter-secret-name: mysecret
>  csi.storage.k8s.io/snapshotter-secret-namespace: mysecretnamespace
> ```
>
> The common snapshot controller reserves the parameter keys  `csi.storage.k8s.io/snapshotter-secret-name`  and  `csi.storage.k8s.io/snapshotter-secret-namespace`. If specified, it fetches the referenced Kubernetes secret and sets it as an annotation on the volume snapshot content object. The CSI external-snapshotter sidecar retrieves it from the content annotation and passes it to the CSI driver during snapshot creation.
>
> Creation of a volume snapshot is triggered by the creation of a VolumeSnapshot API object.
>
> The VolumeSnapshot object must specify the following source type:  `persistentVolumeClaimName`  - The name of the PVC to snapshot. Please note that the source PVC, PV, and VolumeSnapshotClass for a VolumeSnapshot object must point to the same CSI driver.

You can create `VolumeSnapshot` which in this example will make s snapshot of PVC called `test-pvc`:

```yaml
apiVersion: snapshot.storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: VolumeSnapshot
metadata:
  name: test-snapshot
spec:
  volumeSnapshotClassName: test-snapclass
  source:
    persistentVolumeClaimName: test-pvc
```

> When volume snapshot creation is invoked, the common snapshot controller first creates a VolumeSnapshotContent object with the `volumeSnapshotRef`, source `volumeHandle`, `volumeSnapshotClassName` if specified, `driver`, and `deletionPolicy`.

You can restore PersistentVolumeClaim from a Volume Snapshot:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: restore-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: csi-hostpath-sc
  dataSource:
    name: test-snapshot
    kind: VolumeSnapshot
    apiGroup: snapshot.storage.k8s.io
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

> To enable support for restoring a volume from a volume snapshot data source, enable the  `VolumeSnapshotDataSource`  feature gate on the apiserver and controller-manager.

What are the limitations?

> - Does not support reverting an existing volume to an earlier state represented by a snapshot (beta only supports provisioning a new volume from a snapshot).
> - No snapshot consistency guarantees beyond any guarantees provided by storage system (e.g. crash consistency). These are the responsibility of higher level APIs/controllers

EDIT:

To automate this process you would need to setup a `CronJob` or write a Python code using [Python client library for kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) and change for example [python/examples/custom_object.py](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/custom_object.py) to your needs.

You can also use already developed apps like [stash.run](https://stash.run/).

Comment: But how to automate this periodically? I want to take `VolumeSnapshot` everyday. How is that possible without using any operators?

Comment: @NirmalRaghavan, I've edited the answer to provide a bit more info.

Comment: How to perform `VolumeSnapshot` using `CronJob`? I couldn't relate. I never thought about using kubernetes client libraries. Thanks!

Comment: If you create a `yaml` which will create the snapshot it can be used via `kubectl` command, but you can do the same inside the `pod` that have binaries for `kubectl` installed. You will need to deal with ServiceAccount and Roles for that `pod` so it can create resources.

Comment: @Crou that's a nice response but did you actually try what you wrote in EDIT section? I can't figure out how to set those things up, as python client doesn't understand `snapshot.storage.k8s.io/v1beta1`, if I'm not mistaken. Please see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61958371/how-to-run-periodic-volume-snapshots-using-k8s-client-and-cronjob

Answer (score 0):

Velero does offer periodic volume snapshots. I would probably start there.