# How to run kubectl commands in a cron

Tags: kubernetes, cron, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-volumes

I created a schedule configuration inside my Gcloud project to create snapshots of a bunch of virtual disks.

Now I want to add my schedule configuration to my disks, but I dont know how to do it in a automated way, because I have more than 1200 disks.

I tryed to use a POD with a cron inside, but I cannot execute the kubectl command to list all my persistent volumes:

```
kubectl describe pv | grep "Name" | awk 'NR % 2 == 1' | awk '{print $2}'
```

I want to use this list with the next command in a Loop to add automatically my programmed schedule to my disks:

```
gcloud compute disks add-resource-policies [DISK_NAME] --resource-policies [SCHEDULE_NAME] --zone [ZONE]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit 1: After some comments I changed my code to add a Kubernetes CronJob, but the result is the same, the code doesn't work (the pod is created, but it gives me an error: ImagePullBackOff):

```
resource "kubernetes_cron_job" "schedulerdemo" {
  metadata {
    name = "schedulerdemo"
  }
  spec {
    concurrency_policy            = "Replace"
    failed_jobs_history_limit     = 5
    schedule                      = "*/5 * * * *"
    starting_deadline_seconds     = 10
    successful_jobs_history_limit = 10
    job_template {
      metadata {}
      spec {
        backoff_limit = 2
        ttl_seconds_after_finished    = 10
        template {
          metadata {}
          spec {
            container {
              name    = "scheduler"
              image   = "imgscheduler"
              command = ["/bin/sh", "-c", "date; kubectl describe pv | grep 'Name' | awk 'NR % 2 == 1' | awk '{print $2}'"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "i cannot execute the kubectl command"? also, it would probably be better not to run cron inside a pod, but use kubernetes `CronJob` ressource instead (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/).

Comment: The reason kubectl may not be working is because you have not given it a ServiceAccount and that's why kubectl cannot authenticate with your cluster. However, following Markus' solution, I would also rather use a Cronjob resource and run a shell script that issues the gcloud command. To fully solve this, you'll need just one ServiceAccount that can list and describe persistent disks, also use that same service account to link it to an IAM entity in GCP.

Comment: I followed your comments and I changed a bit the code in my terraform code to create a CronJob:

I pasted the code in the question.

Comment: `ImagePullBackOff` error means that it cannot find the image as specified in the `image` attribute. Is this image is in your container registry?

Comment: Ok, shame on me, wrong image name. Now I have an error in the Container Log:
/bin/sh: kubectl: not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the comment:

> Ok, shame on me, wrong image name. Now I have an error in the Container Log: /bin/sh: kubectl: not found

It means that the image that you are using doesn't have `kubectl` installed (or it's not in the `PATH`). You can use image: `google/cloud-sdk:latest`. This image already have `cloud-sdk` installed which includes:

- `gcloud`
- `kubectl`

---

To run a `CronJob` that will get the information about `PV`'s and change the configuration of `GCP` storage  you will need following accesses:

- `Kubernetes/GKE` API(`kubectl`) - `ServiceAccount` with a `Role` and `RoleBinding`.
- `GCP` API (`gcloud`) - `Google Service account` with `IAM` permissions for storage operations.

I found this links helpful when assigning permissions to list `PV`'s:

- *[Kubernetes.io: RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)*
- *[Success.mirantis.com: Article: User unable to list persistent volumes](https://success.mirantis.com/article/user-unable-to-list-persistent-volumes)*

The recommended way to assign specific permissions for `GCP` access:

> Workload Identity is the recommended way to access Google Cloud services from applications running within GKE due to its improved security properties and manageability.
>
> -- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Workload Identity: How to](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity)*

I encourage you to read documentation I linked above and check other [alternatives](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#alternatives).

---

As for the script used inside of a `CronJob`. You should look for `pdName` instead of `Name` as the `pdName` is representation of the `gce-pd` disk in `GCP` (assuming that we are talking about in-tree plugin).

You will have multiple options to retrieve the disk name from the API to use it in the `gcloud` command.

One of the options:

```sh
kubectl get pv -o yaml | grep "pdName" | cut -d " " -f 8 | xargs -n 1 gcloud compute disks add-resource-policies --zone=ZONE --resource-policies=POLICY
```

> Disclaimer!
>
> Please treat above command only as an **example**.

Above command will get the `PDName` attribute from the `PV`'s and iterate with each of them in the command after `xargs`.

Some of the things to take into consideration when creating a script/program:

- Running this command more than once on a single disk will issue an error that you cannot assign multiple policies. You  could have a list of already configured disks that do not require assigning a policy.
- Consider using `.spec.concurrencyPolicy: Forbid` instead of `Replace`. Replaced `CronJob` will start from the beginning iterating over all of those disks. Command could not complete in the desired time and `CronJob` will be replaced.
- You will need to check for the correct `kubectl` version as the official support allows +1/-1 version difference between client and a server (`cloud-sdk:latest` uses `v1.19.3`).

---

I highly encourage you to look on other methods to backup your `PVC`'s (like for example `VolumeSnapshots`).

Take a look on below links for more reference/ideas:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Answer: Periodic database backup in kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60931080/12257134)*
- *[Stash.run: Guides: Latest: Volumesnapshot: PVC](https://stash.run/docs/v0.9.0-rc.2/guides/latest/volumesnapshot/pvc/)*
- *[Velero.io](https://velero.io/)*

It's worth to mention that:

> CSI drivers are the future of storage extension in Kubernetes. **Kubernetes has announced that the in-tree volume plugins are expected to be removed from Kubernetes in version 1.21.** For details, see [Kubernetes In-Tree to CSI Volume Migration Moves to Beta](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/12/09/kubernetes-1-17-feature-csi-migration-beta/). After this change happens, existing volumes using in-tree volume plugins will communicate through CSI drivers instead.
>
> -- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Persistent Volumes: GCE PD CSI Driver: Benefits of using](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/gce-pd-csi-driver#benefits_of_using)*

Switching to `CSI` plugin for your `StorageClass` will allow you to use `Volume Snapshots` inside of `GKE`:

> Volume snapshots let you create a copy of your volume at a specific point in time. You can use this copy to bring a volume back to a prior state or to provision a new volume.
>
> -- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Persistent Volumes: Volume snaphosts: How to](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/volume-snapshots)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Persistent Volumes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Cronjobs: How to](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cronjobs)*
- *[Terraform.io: Kubernetes: CronJob](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/cron_job)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: Compute: Disks: Create snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots)*

Comment: OMG, so much information! Thanks a lot! I will read it all and then test some of the solutions that you offered me.

Right now, to avoid the use of a cron, I launched the google commands to test if they work. And yes I found that error of multiple policies forbidden.

Comment: One more question about this: there is a way to restore a GCE snapshot into a Persistent Volume without use a CSI driver?

Comment: @BarragánLouisenbairn Yes, please take a look here: [use snapshot to create a disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/restore-and-delete-snapshots#restore_a_snapshot_of_a_persistent_disk_to_a_new_disk) and here: [use preexisting disk as PV](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/preexisting-pd).

Comment: After some test, I changed my project to have a cluster with the CSI driver. I changed all versions (cluster + nodes), configured the CSI driver and configured my Persistent Volume Claim to the standard-rwo storageClass. Now I am trying to understand how to create a Snapshot Volume Class.

Comment: @BarragánLouisenbairn please take a look on this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/volume-snapshots